# Kotlin infinity loop on list in recursion

Tags: kotlin

This follows infinite loop, in clojure such things just fine

```
tailrec fun passHeaders (xH: List<Int>) 
{
    while (xH.isNotEmpty())
    {
        passHeaders(xH.drop(1))
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect that loop to terminate?

Comment: Why all the negative votes?

Answer (score 2):

`List.drop` does not mutate the `List`, but rather produces a new `List` instance. Thus, you're `while` loop is infinite.

Comment: It is not, but produce new one

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide a base case, that's why. Because in each call to `passHeaders`, `xH` is it's own copy, it will NEVER not be empty. Remember, when you call `drop()`, a new list is created.

```
while (xH.isNotEmpty())
```

What this says is "while my copy of `xH` is not empty, call `passHeaders`.

On the other hand:

```
if (xH.isNotEmpty())
```

Will probably do what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to this function will never terminate if `xH` isn't empty. [`.drop()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop.html) doesn't modify the original list.

Comment: It is not, but produce new one